# HTML/CSS: Input number is in range by default

Tags: html, css, input, onfocus

I have an input number tag, with a min value of 3 and max of 999. I want it to highlight with green if a number in range is entered, and to highlightwith  red if a number out of range is entered.

The problem is that it is by default highlighted green. Why is it doing this and how do I make it so it only highlights green after a number in range is entered?

HTML:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="No#" min="3" max="999">
```

CSS:

```
    input:focus {
        border: 3px solid lightslategray;
    }

    input[type="number"]:not(:focus):out-of-range {
        border: 3px solid red;
    }

    input[type="number"]:not(:focus):in-range {
        border: 3px solid green;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The highlight only changes if you focus out from the input. Instead, you can remove the part that specifies that the green highlight should only occur when you focus out:

```css
    input:focus {
        border: 3px solid lightslategray;
    }

    input[type="number"]:out-of-range {
        border: 3px solid red;
    }

    input[type="number"]:in-range {
        border: 3px solid green;
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="No#" min="3" max="999">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that browser see empty value and mark it as acceptable, i don't think u can do some thing with it in just html\css, because u need to validate empty value after focus out, but browser won't.